# Text doesn't fit in UIButton titleLabel height for a specific font

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uibutton

I have had some troubles with a specific font i am using. It's made for Schools so A and Å is not the same height. I think it causes troubles for my UIButtons. I've tried to work around it but can't seem to get it right. This is what I've tried last:

```
[self setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:220] forKeyPath:@"button1.font"];
[self setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:220] forKeyPath:@"button2.font"];
[self setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:220] forKeyPath:@"button3.font"];
[button1 setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setTitle:@"Å" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button3 setTitle:@"Å" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(button2.frame.origin.x, button2.frame.origin.y, button2.frame.size.width, button2.frame.size.height+100)];
[button2.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(button2.frame.origin.x, button2.frame.origin.y, button2.frame.size.width, button2.frame.size.height)];
button2.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
```

This is the result:

[image: The Å is not displayed properly.]

The Å is not displayed properly as you can see. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Joakim

Comment: can you set `clipsToBounds` to be `No` for the button/label?

Comment: Hi @LouisTur thanks for your comment. I added those two lines.

    `button3.clipsToBounds = NO;
    button3.titleLabel.clipsToBounds = NO;`

Had no effect at all.

Comment: Where is `button3`'s frame? It's impossible to tell with the white background. Even if you set it to not clip to the button's bounds, if the Å extends beyond the frame of the button, it could still be cut off. Try setting `button2.titleLabel.clipsToBounds = NO` instead as it clearly has the excess frame real estate.

Comment: @Stonz2 I tried the same thing on button2, no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im posting another answer to this problem myself.
After i had other issues with the font I decided to edit the font in a Font editor, i used glyph.
When i exported the font after some edits to other characters, the Å started to work in my app.
So please try to regenerate your fonts using a font editor before you make custom optimization in the code.

Answer (score 18):

I used the following way to solve the problem.

Suppose that you have a UIButton in your xib or storyboard, 
then

1. Select the UIButton
2. Go to Attributes Inspector
3. Find Control Category
4. Find Alignment
5. Choose the right most side button of the Vertical property!

[image]

Comment: That seems to be equivalent to setting the control's `contentVerticalAlignment` property to `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill`

Comment: Yes, I had a problem with an accent in a custom font in the button´s title. So, the accent was not viewed completely due to font internal guidelines. The default "wrapped" height of the title button was creating the issue. Then, once the control (title = UILabel) is filling UIButton vertical height, fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT

This particular font has some oddities with how it is actually drawn. In particular, it is offset a good bit "up" from a center/baseline.

### Original

I've had to do a similar thing with a `UILabel`, and here's what I did to adapt that to a `UIButton` subclass:

```
//  PaddedButton.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PaddedButton : UIButton
@property (assign, nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets padding;
@end

//  PaddedButton.m
#import "PaddedButton.h"
@implementation PaddedButton
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    CGSize size = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return CGSizeMake(size.width + self.padding.left + self.padding.right, size.height + self.padding.top + self.padding.bottom);
}
@end
```

Then, in my `UIViewController` subclass, I instantiated a button this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.buttonFontSize                     = 200;
    self.buttonFont                         = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.buttonFontSize];
    self.button                             = [[PaddedButton alloc] init];
    self.button.backgroundColor             = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f];
    self.button.contentVerticalAlignment    = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
    self.button.padding                     = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    [self.button setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Å" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.buttonFont}] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[button]-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"button": self.button}]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(40)-[button]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"button": self.button}]];
}
```

## New Code Section

After struggling with this for some time, it occurred to me that there were easier ways to do this. Also, when trying to use a button with a set `title` or `attributedTitle`, things got really wonky, with the button drawing its title and then my code re-drawing the title in the correct spot.

Finally, I came up with this solution, which seems to work well:

#### Button Class

```
//  PaddedButton.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PaddedButton : UIButton
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *title;
@property (assign, nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets   padding;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont        *font;
@end

//  PaddedButton.m
#import "PaddedButton.h"
@implementation PaddedButton
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    NSAttributedString *title   = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.title attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.font}];
    CGRect textRect             = [title boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
    CGSize textSize             = textRect.size;
    return CGSizeMake(textSize.width + self.padding.left + self.padding.right, textSize.height + self.padding.top + self.padding.bottom);
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSAttributedString *title   = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.title attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.font}];
    CGRect textRect             = [title boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
    textRect                    = CGRectIntegral(textRect);
    CGFloat xOffset             = (rect.size.width  - textRect.size.width)  / 2.0f;
    CGFloat yOffset             = (rect.size.height - textRect.size.height) / 2.0f;
    CGRect titleRect            = CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, textRect.size.width, textRect.size.height);
    // Show the bounding rect where the button WANTS to put the title
    CGContextRef ctx            = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextStrokeRect(ctx, titleRect);
    // From my testing, this offset will center the "Å" (accented) character.
    // The "A" (no accent) will be offset a little bit below center, due to the lack of accent.
    // You might want to play around with exactly what particular value is best.
    titleRect                   = CGRectOffset(titleRect, 0.0f, titleRect.size.height * 36.0f / 276.0f);
    NSLog(@"titleRect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(titleRect));
    [title drawInRect:titleRect];
}
@end
```

#### Button Setup in View Controller

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UI Setup
- (void)setupUserInterface {
    [self createConstants];
    [self createControls];
    [self setupControls];
    [self layoutControls];
    self.view.backgroundColor   = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
- (void)createConstants {
    self.buttonFontSize         = 200;
    self.buttonFont             = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Skolrak" size:self.buttonFontSize];
}
- (void)createControls {
    self.button                 = [[PaddedButton alloc] init];
}
- (void)setupControls {
    self.button.backgroundColor             = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f];
    self.button.contentVerticalAlignment    = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
    self.button.font                        = self.buttonFont;
    self.button.title                       = @"Å";
    self.button.title                       = @"A";
    self.button.padding                     = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    [self.button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
}
- (void)layoutControls {
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[button]-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"button": self.button}]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(20)-[button]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"button": self.button}]];
}
```

Here are my results (the box is drawn just to see where the button **wants** to put the title):
[image: Accented Letter]
[image: Non-accented Letter]

Is this suitable for you?

Comment: Hi @mbm29414, thanks for your suggestion and detailed answer.
I changed button2 to subclass UIButton into my custom button and created h/m files for that buttonclass as you described. Below an image of the result. Not working for me..
<img src="http://i926.photobucket.com/albums/ad109/joakimserholtjoakimserholt/Ska3080rmavbild2015-01-08kl110752_zpsa0dd924c.png">

Comment: Code i used:
`button2.backgroundColor             = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f];
    button2.contentVerticalAlignment    = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    button2.padding                     = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
    [button2 setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Å" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"SKOLRAK" size:220]}] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`

Comment: @JoakimSerholt Where are you getting that font? I see one called "Skolar". I'd like to test with the exact parameters you're using to make sure I get this right.

Comment: i've shared it temporary on this link, please let me know when you have received it so I can remove it again: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7306301/SKOLRAK.TTF

Comment: @JoakimSerholt Got it. I'll get back to you when I can.

Comment: @JoakimSerholt Does the updated code get you your desired outcome?

Comment: Hi @mbm29414!
Thanks a lot, it seems to work great. But i need to change some code to set `button.title` instead of using `[button setTitle:@""];` also need to play a bit to get it in correct position, but that should be no big deal i hope. I have tons of places where I'm using UIButtons for displaying these letters, so quite some work to get all changed.
Also i would like to remove the borders and change the font color, is that possible?

Comment: Also, try setting `@"Q"` as text instead of @"Å". Does that fit into your title label?

Comment: @JoakimSerholt Sure, you can remove the border by simply removing the call to `CGContextStrokeRect(ctx, titleRect)`. To change the color, you'll probably be best to add a property to `PaddedButton` that is a `UIColor`, then you just add that to the `NSAttributedString` attributes (`NSForegroundColorName: self.titleColor` or something).

Comment: As for "Q", yes, it does fit within the drawn box, but it's a good bit lower. Unfortunately, this font appears to be interesting with how it renders on-screen, so a good bit of experimenting may be in order.

Comment: Im using font size 220, maybe thats why. i Have to increase the rect size a bit?

Comment: If you use the code I've provided, and set the font before asking the button to render, it should automatically adjust for the font size. Also, this exposes a problem with my quick-and-dirty class that you'd need to remedy. Changing properties doesn't automatically cause the button to redraw itself. You could change that by implementing/overriding custom accessors.

Comment: I managed to get this working as I wanted it to be using this implementation. I removed the offset completely and resized my button in my story board to be high enough for both Å and Q to fit. Thanks alot @mbm29414.

Comment: Hi @mbm29414, please see my answer below. Just wanted to let you know how i got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

if you have an image also and dont want it to be scaled this worked for me

```
btn.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
btn.contentMode = .center
btn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for arabic fonts. For that, I just set the frame of titlelabel in viewdidlayoutsubviews.
Try this.. Hope it helps.. Let me know if it worked for you too :)

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
       [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
       [button2.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(button2.frame.origin.x, button2.frame.origin.y, button2.frame.size.width, button2.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just increase button height** a few point. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same it works as @YuAn Shaolin Maculelê Lai mentioned

**Swift 3.2 code is:** `button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill`